# CDKでLambdaのトリガーにcloudwatch eventsを指定したい

Tags: python, python3, aws

CDKでLambdaのトリガーにcloudwatch eventsをトリガーに指定したいのですが
書き方がわかりません。

お教えいただけたら幸いです。

cdk ver: 1.13.1
言語: Python

```
from aws_cdk import (
    core,
    aws_iam,
    aws_ec2,
    aws_stepfunctions,
    aws_lambda,
    aws_cloudwatch,
    aws_events,
    aws_events_targets,
)


class CdkPrjStack(core.Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: core.Construct, id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, id, **kwargs)

        lambda_function = aws_lambda.Function(
            self,
            id='lambda',
            code=aws_lambda.Code.asset('trigger_lambda/lambda'),
            handler='lambda_function.lambda_handler',
            runtime=aws_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_7,
            function_name='sfn-trigger',
            environment=None,
            timeout=core.Duration.seconds(900),
            reserved_concurrent_executions=1,
            vpc=None,
            vpc_subnets=None,
            role=None,
        )

        schedule = aws_events.Schedule.cron(
            year='*',
            month='*',
            day='*',
            hour='15',
            minute='*',
        )

        rule = aws_events.Rule(
            self,
            id='cloudwatch-event',
            description=None,
            enabled=True,
            event_pattern=None,
            schedule=schedule,
            rule_name='ami-region-copy',
        )

        rule_target_input = aws_events.RuleTargetInput.bind(
            self,
            rule=rule,
        )

        aws_events_targets.LambdaFunction(
            handler=lambda_function,
            event=rule_target_input,
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

ruleにtargetsのこのように指定することで解決できました

```
rule = aws_events.Rule(
            self,
            id='cloudwatch-event',
            description=None,
            enabled=True,
            event_pattern=None,
            schedule=schedule,
            rule_name='ami-region-copy',
            targets=[aws_events_targets.LambdaFunction(handler=lambda_function)],
        )
```